# Notifications not working when app is swiped away

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm writing a simple app that sets up to 8 random, repeating alarms, sends a notification, and then generates a quote when the user taps on the notification. This all seems to work properly when the app is running but when the app is swiped away from the recent apps, or force closed, the notifications don't work.

I've poured over my research from the last several days and can't find a solution that's current or fixes my problem. The most common thing I've seen is to use onReceive to set up a service, but my reading has shown me that this no longer works with Oreo and is outdated advice. I've also seen some stuff about foreground services, but I'm really not looking to have a persistent notification bothering the user.

I've also seen some people say to do some work in onDestroy, but that hasn't worked for me either. A lot of the stuff I've found has said that this kind of behavior is "expected behavior", as the system assumes that if an app is swiped away, the user no longer wants it doing anything. I don't want this happening and there must be some way around it, since reminders and notifications from other apps are able to come through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for a long time. I'll post my code for setting alarms below, as well as the code for setting up the notification channels and the BroadcastReceiver class.

By the way, my test device is a Pixel 2XL with Android 9.

```
//method to save preferences when the user clicks "SAVE"
    private fun saveData() {

        if (NOTIFICATIONS_PER_DAY > 0) {
            setAlarms()
        } else {
            clearAlarms() //clearing if the user is removing notifications
        }

        val sharedPreferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        editor.putString(THEME_PREF, THEME_SELECTED)
        editor.putInt(NOTS_PREF, NOTIFICATIONS_PER_DAY)

        editor.apply()

        Toast.makeText(context, "Settings saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }//saveData method

    //method to set repeating notification alarms (random times)
    private fun setAlarms() {
        //clearing any previously saved alarms to prevent tons of extra
        clearAlarms()
        calList.clear()


        var hour: Int
        var minute: Int

        for (i in 0 until (NOTIFICATIONS_PER_DAY)) {
            val hourRand = (0..23).random()
            val minuteRand = (0..59).random()

            hour = hourRand
            minute = minuteRand
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

            calList.add(cal)
        }//for

        var i = 0
        for (cal in calList) {
            val alarmManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val intent = Intent(context, AlertReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0)

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent)
            println(i)
            i++
        }//for

    }//setAlarms method
```

```
class BetterDays : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannels()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel1 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Quote Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).apply { description = "New quotes notification" }
            channel1.enableLights(true)
            channel1.enableVibration(true)
            //channel1.description = "New quotes notification"

/*            val channel2 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_2_ID, "New Quote!", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channel2.enableLights(true)
            channel2.enableVibration(true)
            channel2.description = "New quotes notification" */

            val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1)
            //manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2)
        }

    }//createNotificationChannels method

    companion object {

        val CHANNEL_1_ID = "quotes notification"
        val CHANNEL_2_ID = "quotes notification 2"
    }
}
```

```
class AlertReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private var notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat? = null
    private var theContext: Context? = null

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        theContext = context
        sendOnChannel1()
    }//onReceive method

    private fun sendOnChannel1() {
        val title = "New Quote Available"
        val message = "Come check it out!"

        var index: Int = 0
        if(quotesList.size != 0) {
            index = Random.nextInt(quotesList.size)
        }//if
        quoteText = quotesList[index]
        speakerText = speakersList[index]

        quoteTextView?.text = quotesList[index]
        speakerTextView?.text = speakersList[index]


        val intent = Intent(theContext!!, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("From", "quotesFragment")

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(theContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(theContext!!, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_quotes)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()

        val id = createID()

        notificationManager!!.notify(id, notification)

    }//sendOnChannel1 method

/*    //for future functionality
    fun sendOnChannel2() {
        val title = "Title"
        val message = "Message"

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(theContext!!, CHANNEL_2_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_quotes)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .build()

        notificationManager!!.notify(2, notification)

    }//sendOnChannel2 method*/

    //method to generate a unique ID
    private fun createID(): Int{
        val now = Date()
        val id = Integer.parseInt(SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss", Locale.US).format(now))
        return id
    }//createID method
}//AlertReceiver class
```

Answer (score -1):

Some chinese device with their own modified android system so when the apps are swiped from the recent app tray your app gets terminated (similar to Force Stop). And due to this every task running in the background like Services, Jobs gets killed with the app. Even High priority FCM doesn’t see the daylight in Chinese ROMs.

you can read in here : https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6

maybe can help ;)

Comment: Hm, this seems to be limited to the aggressive nature of Chinese ROMs. I can't even get the desired behavior from stock Android on a Pixel. Apps that give reminders or messages or anything like that all seem to work, but I'm not sure how they're able to accomplish it.

Comment: Another app that working fine is because the Chinese roms is take that app (famous app) in the white list,if you can see the famous app like google,wa,fb,ig is locked in the background by default. So when the user swipe recent app the app that has been locked not closed.